# Is it ok to put a plug on a light fitting?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I want to put some extra lighting in my workshop but don't have much to spend so am looking to do it all myself if possible. I'm looking to use led battens, similar to [this one](https://www.electricalcounter.co.uk/products/Lighting/Indoor+Lighting/Selectric+Indoor+Lighting/GloLine+Battens/White+GloLine65+4ft+Twin+LED+Batten+Fitting+5000K+IP65+40W/2372654565) or [this](https://www.screwfix.com/p/lap-twin-5ft-led-batten-white-60w-5600lm/7223v), but not exactly sure at the moment (or I may use simple pendant and ceiling rose fitting).

My plan is use wire this onto a plug (3A fuse) with flex cable which I can route from the socket to the ceiling.

Would this work and is it safe? When I have a bit more time and money in a few months i will look to get an electrician to properly add it to the lighting circuit. So this would be a semi temporary solution. Does this sound ok? Thanks for any advice you may have.

Comment: So instead of "hard wiring" the light fixture, you want to hook a cord onto it and plug it in?  Is the plug low on the wall like a typical plug?

Comment: yep, pretty much. yes into a regular socket..

Comment: Don't buy anything mains electrical on Amazon.  That particular one is sold by a third-party seller using the Amazon warehouse to dropship straight from China.  99.9% of such products are unsafe, the CE marks are fake, and they don't even bother trying to get UL listings. Things are safer if they say "Ships by and sold from Amazon.com" right under the Buy button, but the better plan is to avoid Amazon altogether.  And eBay and obviously, AliExpress.

Comment: note taken. changed the link to a different product..

Comment: Since this is a temporary install, have you considered a couple of plug-in lights? Then, once you have permanent ones wired in, you'll have a couple of work lights that you can use around the workshop when additional lighting is necessary.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: in the united kingdom

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is "safe" and then there is "safe and legal".  Running what amounts to an extension cord up the wall to a light meant to be hard wired is going to be a code violation and there are subtle safety issues.

As far as "will this work and not kill me", then probably.  The cord needs to be fastened to the wall so no one trips on it or snags it with their hands or something they are carrying.  The connections at the light need to be done properly and fastened securely so the wire can't be puled out.

Would I do this in the living room with kids and visitors?  No, not at all.  But if this is just to get some light in the garage until a real light can be installed?  Sure, but make sure everything is very secure.  The real reason this is dangerous is mostly the cord getting damaged or pulled or having the light fall on your head.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

You must make sure at the lamp end that the flex is **securely** gripped by a suitable cable gland or other strain relief to prevent the cable being tugged out and exposing live wires. Those lamps look like they already have glands, but they might not be the right size for all flexes.

Bear in mind that if you lose power on the socket circuit the lights will go out, but you may have power tools still spinning down. You may want to fit some battery-backed emergency lighting in the workshop, or have lights across multiple circuits/RCDs.